# For loop condition not met, not sure why

Tags: c, for-loop, conditional-statements

With the following code:

```
void pivot(int n, int m, int evi, int lvi, float a[m][n]) {
  int i,j;
  float s = a[lvi][evi];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) a[lvi][i] /= s;
  for (j = 0; (j < m) && (j != lvi); j++) {
    s = a[j][evi];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      a[j][i] -= s * a[lvi][i];
      printf("tab[%d][%d] = %f\n", j, i, a[j][i]);
    }
  }
}
float tab[3][6] = {{0.0}};
tab[0][0] = 200;
tab[0][1] =-200;
tab[0][2] = 60;
tab[0][3] =-60;
tab[0][4] = 1;
tab[1][0] =-100;
tab[1][1] = 100;
tab[1][2] =-150;
tab[1][3] = 150;
tab[1][5] = 1;
```

When I call

```
pivot(6,3,0,0,tab)
```

the second for loop in the pivot function (with && operator) never gets entered, why?

Comment: (j < m) && (j != lvi) j==lvi first time through

Comment: Why do you have `j != lvi` in the loop condition? What is that supposed to accomplish?

Comment: of course but the for loop **never** gets entered

Comment: @ThomasKirven The loop only gets entered when the condition is true.

Comment: Do you think that the condition is not checked before the first iteration?

Comment: @Barmar I don't want the operations being done on the lvi'th row. It's for matrix row reduction.

Comment: Shouldn't j still increment and then the loop would enter when j==1 and j==2??

Comment: only if the condition is true

Answer (score 6):

A `for` loop stops as soon as the condition becomes false. If it's false when the loop starts, the loop is never entered at all.

If you want to skip certain rows, you should put the check in the loop body.

```
  for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    if (j == lvi) {
      continue;
    }
    s = a[j][evi];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      a[j][i] -= s * a[lvi][i];
      printf("tab[%d][%d] = %f\n", j, i, a[j][i]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually had something similar to this initially, but it was having separate weird errors.